# Word 2007 cell formatting

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, forms, timestamp

I have created a form template in Word 2007 which include various fields. Some of the fields are to show time (i.e. `15:47:32`). I’ve set the text field properties as *Date HH:mm:ss*.

The trouble arises when the form is then completed. If I input `15.47.32`, it correctly converts to `15:47:32` but if I input `12.12.31` it converts to `00:00:00`. This also happens if I input `12:12:32`. I’ve looked at this all afternoon now and it’s driving me insane.

Comment: As you've probably figured out the "Date" type is actually a DateTime type, which holds both a date and a time.  My guess as to what's going on: 15.47.32 cannot be converted to a legal date.  So Windows is converting it to the time portion (and probably leaving the Date portion as today).  12.12.32 can be a legit date (Dec. 12, 1932), so Windows is converting it to the Date, and setting the time portion to 12AM on that day.  Unfortunately I don't currently have Word available to me to give you any actual solutions :(

Comment: I understand what Techie007 is saying but within the "Date" type it gives you the option of HH:mm:ss (without any date reference) so I would of thought this would of ignored the date issue.  There is no option to just have a "Time" field.